# Can CPUs run with constant boosted speed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, central-processing-unit, cpu-architecture

My default AWS server CPU speed is 2.5GHz but somehow I did manage to boost it to 3.1GHz. However, when I run `watch -n.1 'cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i mhz'` they are not constantly working with 3.1GHz. They are changing rapidly between 2.5GHz-3.1GHz is it normal is there anything I can do to force CPUs work with 3.1GHz?

Comment: *Why* would you want that? And given that it's AWS: No. You don't control the hardware.

Comment: I'm running blockchain nodes in AWS, in order to keep node sync it needs higher CPU core speeds. That is why it needs to be constantly working on turbo mode.

Comment: You can't. It's not your machine.

Comment: This is controlled by the CPU governors, but probably the AWS machine doesn't have this enabled. Check /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/ if there is any policy directory there.